# Use ffmpeg to create a video from bitmaps with repeating frames and custom order

Tags: video, ffmpeg, jpeg

I can create a video from a series of jpegs named sequentially (pic01.jpg, pic02.jpg, pic03.jpg etc) using this sort of thing:  ffmpeg -f image2 -i pic%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg

That's working fine, but I'd like to create videos that for example play through all the bitmaps forwards and then in reverse.  Or perhaps have the same frame repeated several times.

I could make duplicates of each bitmap with new names and just run the above code, but ideally I'd like to just pass in an array like (pic1.jpg, pic2.jpg, pic2.jpg, pic3.jpg, pic2.jpg, pic1.jpg, pic1.jpg)

Has anyone done this sort of thing, know if it's possible, or have any leads for me?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is fairly specific, so it's possible that the standard ffmpeg executable doesn't support that.  If you run out of options, it wouldn't be hard to patch ffmpeg.c to do what you want to do.